# I can't import torchvision

Tags: python, pytorch, torchvision

I installed torchvision0.12.0, python3.8 and my OS is Windows.
I succeeded in importing torch, but I couldn't import torchvision and getting this error.

ImportError

DLL load failed while importing _imaging:
File "C:\Users'MyName'\Documents\GitHub\pytorch-cifar\main.py", line 8, in 
import torchvision

Is there someone who can solve this problem?

Comment: Are you using Anaconda or pip to install the modules (torch and torchvision)?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I'm using pip to install the modules

Comment: Did you set up a separate environment (something like conda create env env_name python=3.X)?

Comment: No. I set up python3.8 only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may be due to incompatible versions of torch and torchvision.You can get the information you want through the following link:

[the corresponding torchvision versions and supported Python versions](https://pypi.org/project/torchvision/)